# What are the proper parameters for posting flash content using the Facebook Javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, flash, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am able to successfully post Flash content using `FB.ui({method: 'stream_publish',....})`.

However, since my app must also be able to post to Fan Pages, I cannot use FB.ui, and must use the Graph API via FB.api instead. No biggie, I'd rather have a custom form for posting anyway.

But it seems posting to a feed using `FB.api('/FEED_ID/feed', ...)` takes different parameters than the FB.ui method.

Documentation for the [FB.api call](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api) and the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post) is not particularly helpful. The Graph API docs mention a `source` parameter, which is supposed to be the url to the flash object. However, when I set `source` to be the flash object url, I get the following:

---

(#100) flash objects must have the 'swfsrc' and 'imgsrc' attributes.

---

OK, fine, but where do they go? The `attachment` parameter, which worked fine for FB.Connect and FB.ui, seems to be completely ignored.

Here's my code:

```
        body = {
                    name: "Name",
                    link: "http://mysite.com/link_to_my_content",
                    caption: "This is the caption",
                    message: "Test Message",
                    source: 'http://mysite.com/static/flash.swf',
                    image: 'http://mysite.com/static/images/facebook_thumb.png',
                    actions: action_links,
                    description: "The fascinating, compelling description"
                }

                FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', body, function(response){
                    if (!response || response.error){
                        console.log("FB.api error occurred");
                        if (response.error){
                            console.log("Error message: " + response.error.message);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("Post successful: " + response);
                    }
                });
```

When posting to a Fan Page I also include the `access_token` parameter (and changing the url obviously) which seems to work fine. I just can't figure out how to get the flash content to publish. Where do the `swfsrc` and `imgsrc` attributes go? It's probably something that will seem obvious but I've tried everything I can think of. Google isn't helpful as it seems most people are just using `stream_publish`, and a bunch of old FB.Connect stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found out that you ***have*** to supply picture when posting a source swf, or else you receive the imgsrc/swfsrc error message. See http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=10672#c17

Go Facebook.